# GIT repositories but symlinks

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two repositories with the following structure:

```
Project One/
|-application/
|-web/
|-common/

Project Two/
|-application/
|-web/
|-common/
```

But now I want to separate `common` directory **as new repo** and make symlinks to it inside current projects. BUT only locally.

```
Project One/
|.git/
|-application/
|-web/
|-@common

Project Two/
|.git/
|-application/
|-web/
|-@common

Common/
|.git/
|-and/
|-some/
|-common/
|-stuff/
```

Symlinks works fine. But as I said, I want symlinks only locally. **Is it possible** when someone else will `clone` **Project One or Two** will `clone` also **Common** repo and place it inside Project One repo in specific directory?

```
Project One/ <-- main repo
|-application/
|-web/
|-common/ <-- "sub-repo"?
```

Comment: You should consider `git submodule`.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you should go with submodules as already stated. But before you do, make sure to learn what it is hand how it works. It is not that easy to understand. There are a lot of resources out there that will guide you in the right direction, but be sure to aim your time towards newly posted stuff, so you take advantage of all features in GIT regarding submodules.